# Can't connect to Minecraft Lan World

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So my brother and I are connected to the same network, my brother has hosted a LAN world that my dad can connect to but my computer cannot, he has a mac and I have a windows 8 laptop. I have tried disabling windows firewall completely as well as enabling both private and public connections to Java through windows firewall. I have tried using direct connect, both by entering the ipv4:port of LAN as well as just the port. We are all running minecraft 1.9. Help me please because I am dying inside.

Comment: Had problems like this at another house. Wouldn't work.

Comment: Did you make sure you guys have the same mods (or no mods at all)?